# nginx doesn't match server names

Tags: nginx

I created a DNS zone using Bind9 and I'm pretty sure I did it right because when I type my domain name it goes to my server IP.

now comes nginx turn , this is my actual configuration :

```
server{
    listen 80 ;
    server_name  mahkamaty.com;
    return       301 http://www.mahkamaty.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name  www.mahkamaty.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/mahkamaty.com/;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
server{
listen 80 ;
    server_name  www.questions.mahkamaty.com;
     return       301 http://questions.mahkamaty.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name  questions.mahkamaty.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/mahkamaty.com/questions/app/webroot/;
    index index.php;
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

when I go to mahkamaty.com it returns the default page of nginx , which means it doesn't match the server_name .. 
Can you help ? 
PS: i've uploaded the configuration I had saved before , so maybe there is ownership problems of the files in nginx , please confirm or deny this.

Comment: Did you try restarting nginx?

Comment: of course I did

Comment: Do you have any other nginx configuration files or includes? Perhaps a default configuration file with a server definition that is taking precedence over your configuration? What do your error logs report when you try to browse to the domain?

Comment: I reinstalled the nginx with a lower version , from &.6 to 1.2  , I'll tell you what happens